# Remove NodeList from another NodeList

Tags: javascript, nodes

How can I remove one NodeList from another? For example, if I have:

```
var all = document.querySelectorAll('*');
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

var removed = all - divs;
```

This doesn't work however. What is the correct method for doing this with the result being a nodelist and not an array?

Comment: Why would that work? Can you show us what else you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the `all` `nodeList` into an array and then use array methods to do searching and removals:

```
var all = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*'), 0);
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
   var pos = all.indexOf(divs[i]);
   if (pos !== -1) {
       all.splice(pos, 1);
   }
}
```

This requires IE9 (for `.indexOf()`) or you can use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to make it work in older versions of IE or you can make your own function that iterates through an array to find if an element matches.

---

On second thought, there's a bit of an easier way to do this:

```
var all = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*'), 0);
for (var i = all.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   if (all[i].tagName === "DIV") {
      all.splice(i, 1);
   }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be the other way around? for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++). I'm trying to remove divs from all, this doesn't seems to work

Comment: This takes each div, looks for it in the `all` list and removes it if found.

Comment: @user3143218 - I added another way that just moves all items from the `all` list that have a `"DIV"` tagName.

Answer (score -1):

```
var all = document.querySelectorAll('*');
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

var removed = all.filter(function(i){
    return divs.indexOf(i) < 0;
});
```